# Gnuplot 1d plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a text file of the position of particles along the x axis which changes after every collision. Example data.

```
0   7.5 10  30  30  40  
0   9.375   10  32.5    40  40  
0   10  10  33.3333 36.6667 40  
0   10.25   10.75   34  34  40  
0   11.0938 13.2812 28.75   40  40
```

I am currently trying to plot the data using gnu plot. What I want it to do is have these points along the x axis but instead of plotting the whole file at once I would like gnu plot to plot one line at a time . Furthermore, so the data is identifiable I am trying to plot  the points as large markers instead of points. I am struggling to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you have to transpose the data using `awk`, as each row already contains the data of a single particle.

So, based on the code from DragonHu, I have this:
[image]

To generate this plot, I also added lines to connect the points. Also, I used the special column number 0 which just gives the line number in the datafile, starting at 0.

Another trick: Using backslash `\`, you can split a command to multiple lines. Here is the plot command I used:

```
plot "particle.dat" using 1:0 with points linetype 1 pointtype 7 pointsize 3 title "particle 1",\
 "" u 1:0 notitle w l lt 1,\
 "" u 2:0 w p lt 2 pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 2", \
 "" u 2:0 notitle  w l lt 2,\
 "" u 3:0 w p lt 3 pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 3", \
 "" u 3:0 notitle  w l lt 3,\
 "" u 4:0 w p lt 4 pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 4", \
 "" u 4:0 notitle  w l lt 4,\
 "" u 5:0 w p lt 5 pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 5",\
 "" u 5:0 notitle  w l lt 5
```

Still, this is not yet the answer, as the question is to plot one set of points at a time. This can be achieved with the following code. It generates five single plots which I dumped into an animated gif figure:

```
 set key center

 set yrange[0:1]
 set xrange[0:40]

 set terminal gif size 600, 200 animate delay 100

 set output "animated.gif"
 do for [n=0:4] {
     set title sprintf("Lineno. %d", n)

     plot "particle.dat" every ::n::n  using 1:(0) with points pointtype 7 pointsize 3 title "particle 1",\
     "" every ::n::n  u 2:(0) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 2", \
     "" every ::n::n  u 3:(0) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 3", \
     "" every ::n::n  u 4:(0) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 4", \
     "" every ::n::n  u 5:(0) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 5",\


 }
 unset output
```

If single images should be created, it is possible via

```
 set terminal ongcairo 
 do for [n=0:4] {
     set title sprintf("Lineno. %d", n)
     set output sprintf("PictureNumber_%d",n)

     plot ...
     unset output


 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, convert the rows to columns using AWK

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[NR,i]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=1;j<=NR;j++)printf a[j,i]"\t";printf "\n"}}' original.dat > particle.dat
    #suppose that your input data is original.dat and the output data is particle.dat
```

The converted data are:

```
0   0   0   0   0   
7.5 9.375   10  10.25   11.0938 
10  10  10  10.75   13.2812 
30  32.5    33.3333 34  28.75   
30  40  36.6667 34  40  
40  40  40  40  40
```

Then, plot your data with the following code in gnuplot:

```
set border 1
    #`set border 1` means only showing the bottom border of the plot. see `help border` for more information
set xtics nomirror
    #only show the bottom tics on the x axis and suppress the upper tics of the x axis
unset ytics
    #suppress the tics on the y axis
set key outside
    #set the legend out side the plot
plot "particle.dat" using 1:(1) with points pointtype 7 pointsize 3 title "particle 1", "" u 2:(2) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 2", "" u 3:(3) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 3", "" u 4:(4) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 4", "" u 5:(5) w p pt 7 ps 3 t "particle 5"
    #`using 1:(1)` means use the first column as X and a constant number of 1 as Y. see `help using` for more details
    #`u` is short for `using`and `w p pt 7 ps 3` is short for `with points pointtype 7 pointsize 3.
```

The output of the plot is
[image]